# Natural map $f^{\ast}f_\ast\mathcal{L}\to\mathcal{L}$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

Let $f\colon X\to Y$ be a morphism of smooth varieties and $\mathcal{L}$ an invertible sheaf on $X$.

How is the "natural map" 
$$f^{\ast}f_\ast\mathcal{L}\to\mathcal{L}$$
defined (which should be surjective if $f$ is affine) ?

Comment: It should come from the the identity $f_*\mathcal L\to f_*\mathcal L$ and adjunction.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$f^*$ and $f_*$ are adjoint functors, i.e. there is a functorial bijection

$$\operatorname{Hom}(f^* \mathcal G, \mathcal F) = \operatorname{Hom}(\mathcal G, f_*\mathcal F).$$

In particular, for any coherent sheaf $\mathcal F$ on $X$ we have

$$\operatorname{Hom}(f^* f_*\mathcal F, \mathcal F) = \operatorname{Hom}(f_*\mathcal F, f_*\mathcal F),$$

thus the identity map on $f_*\mathcal F$ gives rise to a natural map

$$f^*f_*\mathcal F \to \mathcal F$$

In the affine case $\operatorname{Spec} B \to \operatorname{Spec} A$ with $\mathcal F = M^\sim$, this map is given by

$$M \otimes_A B \to M, m \otimes b \mapsto bm,$$

which is cleary surjective.

In general we cannot reduce to the affine case, but we can reduce to the affine case if $f$ is affine, since in this case around any point $x \in X$ we find some affine open $U \subset Y$, such that $f^{-1}(U) \ni x$ is open affine in $X$. We can check the surjectivity now locally on $f^{-1}(U)$, hence we are in the affine case, where surjectivity holds.

Note that we do not need $\mathcal F$ to be invertible or locally free. We also do not need $X,Y$ to be smooth.

---

Let me also give you an example, where the map is not surjective. Let $X \xrightarrow{f} \operatorname{Spec} k$ be some projective morphism (i.e. $X$ is a projective $k$-variety) and $\mathcal L$ a line bundle without global sections, for example $\mathcal L = \mathcal O_X(-1)$.

On $\operatorname{Speck} k$ - via $H^0(\operatorname{Spec} k,-)$ - a sheaf is the same as a $k$-vector space, i.e. we have

$$f_*\mathcal L=H^0(\operatorname{Spec} k,f_* \mathcal L) = H^0(X,\mathcal L)=0.$$

Thus $f^*f_*\mathcal L \to \mathcal L$ will not be surjective.

In general, for $f: X \to \operatorname{Spec} k$, the map $f^*f_* \mathcal F \to \mathcal F$ is surjective if and only if $\mathcal F$ is globally generated, since it is the map

$$H^0(X, \mathcal F) \otimes_k \mathcal O_X \to \mathcal F.$$

Comment: Dear MooS, thank you for your crystal-clear and very complete answer. Could you explain me how do you manage to explicit out the map as $m \otimes b \mapsto bm$ in the affine case?

Comment: In the affine case, the adjunction between $f^*$ and $f_*$ becomes the Tensor-Hom adjunction (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensor-hom_adjunction) and the co-unit is the evaluation map
$$Hom_B(B,M) \otimes_A B \to M.$$
After using the identification $ Hom_B(B,M)\cong M, \alpha \mapsto \alpha(1)$, this is precisely the map, I have given you for the affine case in my answer.

Comment: If you want to read more about the surjectivity of that map, you should read about quasi-affine morphisms and relatively ample sheaves. Actually the surjectivity of that map can be viewed as a relative version of the term 'globally generated' (Note that I have shown that if $f$ maps to some affine scheme, then surjectivity is equivalent to global generation) and as ample can be defined in terms of global generation, 'relatively ample' can be defined (there are many equivalent statements) in terms of the surjectivity of this map.

Comment: Thank you MooS. Indeed, I found very interesting the connection to global generation in your example. Where do you suggest me to read about relative ampleness?

Comment: Hartshorne does not cover it at all as far as I can remember. Lazarsfeld has a few pages about it. Görtz/Wedhorn have a section on quasi-affine morphisms and relative ampleness respectively, but they do not cover an cohomological properties. I think, if you read those and the few pages in Lazarsfeld, you are off to a good start. You can of course always check the Stacks Project, too.